# Auto Refresh Divs that are on timed Show/Hide Intervals Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got some code for Show/Hide Divs on Intervals from another thread and that part works perfectly. What I need now is to add an auto refresh to those divs only. Not the entire page. 
I have a page that is displaying on a wall monitor that rotates through the content using the code below. The content changes (like upcoming events) so I need these divs to auto refresh so it is displaying the most recent data in the database. 
Can someone tell me what to add to the below code for this? Thanks!

```
$(function () {

var counter = 0,
    divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3');

function showDiv () {
    divs.hide() // hide all divs
        .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }) // figure out correct div to show
        .show('fast'); // and show it

    counter++;
}; // function to loop through divs and show correct div

showDiv(); // show first div    

setInterval(function () {
    showDiv(); // show next div
}, 10 * 1000); // do this every 10 seconds    

});
```

Comment: The divs do not need to be "refreshed". This jQuery code should work as expected. What are your errors ? `setInterval()` should suffice. But if you need to target a div then `$('div').load('content')`

Comment: This code doesn't error. It works great for showing the correct divs on intervals. What I need to ADD to it is for it to 'reload'. Currently, if I make a change in the database, it does not reflect on my display without manually refreshing the page. I need it to be reload automatically. Similiar to this:  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("##currentDate").load("currentTime.cfm");
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("##currentDate").load('currentTime.cfm');
     }, 1000);
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  });